# All versions of differential evolution algorithm

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm, differential-evolution

explain all updates in the basic algorithm of differential evolution. i am not able to find all versions of this algorithm. explain all versions of this algorithm as a survey and i am not clearly understand the theory behind this algorithm as given in the Wikipedia. Wikipedia also define only basic algorithm of differential evolution but i want to all updates of this algorithm

Answer (score 6):

For complete survey in **Differential Evolution**, I suggest you the paper entitled [Differential Evolution: A Survey of the State-of-the-Art](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5601760) but the brief explanation is :

- DE has 2 basic crossover and 5 basic mutation operators, so we have 2*5=10 basic DE variants.
- Two crossover operators are `Exponential` and `Binomial`.

  ***Exponential Crossover:***
  [image]
  `D` is problem space dimensionality, `n` is randomly chosen from [1,D], `Cr` is crossover rate and `L` is drawn from [1,D] according to above pseudocode.

  ***Binomial Crossover:***
  [image]
  `j` is refer to j-th dimension, `i` is vector number and `G` is generation number and `jrand` is randomly chosen index from [1,D].
- Five mutation operators are `DE/rand/1` , `DE/best/1` , `DE/target-to-best/1` , `DE/best/2` and `DE/rand/2`.

  **DE/rand/1:** `V(i)=X(r1)+F*(X(r2)-X(r3))`

  **DE/best/1:** `V(i)=X(best)+F*(X(r1)-X(r2))`

  **DE/target-to-best/1:** `V(i)=X(i)+F*(X(best)-X(i))+F*(X(r1)-X(r2))`

  **DE/best/2:** `V(i)=X(best)+F*(X(r1)-X(r2))+F*(X(r3)-X(r4))`

  **DE/rand/2:** `V(i)=X(r1)+F*(X(r2)-X(r3))+F*(x(r4)-X(r5))`

`V(i)` is donor(mutant) vector for target vector `X(i)`, `F` is difference vector's scale factor, `r1,r2,r3,r4,r5` are mutually exclusive, randomly chosen from [1,NP] and differ from `i`, `best` is the fittest vector's index in the current population, finally `NP` is population size.

- These are all of things you can know about basic variants of DE.
- DE also has many variants for many purposes which has explained in the mentioned paper.